# ruby gem, requiring a rails module bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dependencies

I am working on a ruby gem that parses xml. I want to utilize the rails `Hash.from_xml` method and am wondering if requiring `active_support` or any large library in a gem is bad practice. Is this adding too much just so I can use its one method, or is this considered standard/ok when building a ruby gem? I would be adding `require 'active_support/all'` to my gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to require as little as possible and to only cherry-pick the specific definition that I want to use.

In your example that would look like this:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
```

Read about how to [require only specific definitions from `ActiveSupport` in the official Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#cherry-picking-a-definition).

Comment: I echo what spickermann indicated.  Noting the 'all' at the end of your requirement statement there isn't wrong, but you are potentially adding more than you absolutely need to.  It is a best practice where I work, and the school I went to, to only include what you are using in your code.